# Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'gameManager.CompleteLevel()'

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm taking a tutorial by Brackeys for a Unity Game and for some reason my code is returning this Error- An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'gameManager.CompleteLevel()'

here is some of the code/context

```
public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool gameHasEnded = false;
    public float restartdelay = 11f;

    public void CompleteLevel()//here is the Error
    {
        Debug.Log("LEVEL COMPLETED");//printing this to make sure it works
    }

    public void gameEnd()
    {
        if (gameHasEnded == false)
        {
            gameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
            Invoke("Restart", 2f);//here making a delay
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is some more of the code-------------------------------------------------------------------- //im trying to make the restart function
    }     
    void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    } 

}

Comment: i'm using-----
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

Comment: Can you edit your code inline?

Comment: You should name your classes in PascalCase. i.e. `GameManager` instead of `gameManager` in order to distinguish between ClassesTypes and instanceObjects.

Answer (score 0):

`Error- An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'gameManager.CompleteLevel()'` happens because you are trying to access something directly, without it being static or by not using a reference. You need to decide if you want this method, or class, to be [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) or create a reference to it.

You only need to do this to make it static

```
public static void CompleteLevel()//here is the Error
{
    Debug.Log("LEVEL COMPLETED");//printing this to make sure it works
}
```

Comment: While static will let the code compile it is not *necessarily* the correct thing to do. It will probably work out fine, as `gameManager` may be used like a singleton, but as it is a `MonoBehaviour` component, that may not be true and there may be changes the asker makes that result in undesired behaviour caused by the fact that this method is now static.